# Python regex to validate this format of string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm having trouble validating this type of input strings in Python.

The weekday have a variable number of characters.

```
Regular: 16Mar2009(mon), 17Mar2009(tues), 18Mar2009(wed)
Regular: 20Mar2009(fri), 21Mar2009(sat), 22Mar2009(sun)
Rewards: 26Mar2009(thur), 27Mar2009(fri), 28Mar2009(sat)
```

I want to validate the whole line, every line should have this specific format:

```
<name>: <date>(<weekday>), <date>(<weekday>), <date>(<weekday>)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `\w+: \d+\w+\(\w+\)(?:,\s*\d+\w+\(\w+\))*`

Using programs like [kiki-re](https://code.google.com/p/kiki-re/) you can test regexps easily.

Comment: This does work for the given examples, but is not very strict.  For example, it allows for more than three entries per line, and allows for all sorts of other invalid input.  `\w`'s scope goes beyond the alphabet.

Comment: All valid concerns.  My intention was to provide a starting point to improve upon. We don't know all constraints.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regular: 20Mar2009(fri), 21Mar2009(sat), 22Mar2009(sun)

your_regex = r'^[A-Za-z]+:\s+(?:\d{1,2}[A-Za-z]{3}\d{4}\([A-Za-z]{3}\),\s+){2}
               \d{1,2}[A-Za-z]{3}\d{4}\([A-Za-z]{3}\)$'
```

To see how this works, see the picture and explanations below:
[image]

NB: You could use `\w`, but the character class corresponding to `\w` is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

`r` means interpret as a raw string
`^` means begins with 
`[A-Za-z]` means any character that is in the character class A,B,C...Z and a, b, c, ...z 
`+` means 1 or more of the preceding 
`:` matches the literal colon 
`\s` means whitespace 
`(?:...)` means group, but do not capture (see capturing groups for the alternative `(...)`
`{x,y}` means that there must exist [x,y] of whatever precedes this 
`{x}` means that there must exist exactly 'x' of whatever came before this 
`\(` and `\)` mean `(` and `)`, but need to be preceded by `\` since parenthesis are special characters in regular expressions. 
`$` means ends with

While this may not be exactly what you want, it works for your input and you now hopefully have the tools to change it to fit your needs.  You should consider edges cases, though, for example in the proposed solution above, you could easily match: `blah: 99zzz0000...`  Good luck!